# What does the `0".>,.2}.` part do in the J-script?

Tags: j

Recently I had the glorious idea to use `J` as a scripting language (otherwise I will never use J anywhere). The sample from the [jsoftware](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Guides/J_Shell_Script) page works as promised. Here for reference the code for `sumsquares`:

```
#!/home/fred/j807/bin/jconsole
echo +/*:0".>,.2}.ARGV
exit''
```

As far as I know the `ARGV` is a boxed list with contents (with `1 2 3` as the arguments):

```
┌────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬─┬─┬─┐
│/home/fred/j807/bin/jconsole│./sumsquares.ijs│1│2│3│
└────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴─┴─┴─┘
```

However, when executed in the J REPL, it fails with (I hope this is not just some stupid mistake on my side):

```
    +/*:0".>,.2}. ('/home/fred/j807/bin/jconsole';'./sumsquares.ijs';1;2;3)
|domain error
|   +/*:0    ".>,.2}.('/home/fred/j807/bin/jconsole';'./sumsquares.ijs';1;2;3)
```

I think, I can decipher parts of it:

- `2}.`: beheading the two string elements
- `>`: unboxing/opening the elements

But the rest is a bit of a mystery. Could any one explain me what is going on in `0".>,.2}.`? Especially the thing with the `0`.

Also:
Why does it work inside the script but not in the REPL?

- Works in Script: `echo +/*:0".>,.2}.ARGV`
- Works NOT in REPL: `+/*:0".>,.2}.('/home/fred/j807/bin/jconsole';'./sumsquares.ijs';1;2;3)`

A modified version works the opposite way:

- Works NOT in script: `echo +/*:@:>2}.ARGV`
- Works in REPL: `+/*:@:>2}.('/home/fred/j807/bin/jconsole';'./sumsquares.ijs';1;2;3)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell command line passes arguments as *strings*.  When `jconsole` receives control, `ARGV` is a boxed array of *strings*, some of which *look* like numbers.

So, in your example above, final three elements of the boxed array in `ARGV` are the *strings*: '1' '2' '3', *not* the *digits* 1, 2, 3.

In the REPL, when given an expression like this:

```
'sumsquares';1;2;3
```

the result is a boxed array containing a string, followed by three *numbers* *(**not** strings)*.

The expression `0".y` is called *Numbers* and its function is to convert the elements of array y from *strings* to numbers, replacing *bad numbers* with `0`.  But a `Domain error` will occur if the array contains non-strings.

See these examples:

```
   0".'123'
123
   0".'1.23'
1.23
   0".'1.23.4'
0
   0".'abc'
0
   0".123
|domain error
|   0    ".123
```

So, the mixed use of *numbers* where *strings* are expected is contributing to your confusion.

Finally, the REPL line that works correctly would be:

```
   +/*:0".>,.2}. ('/home/fred/j807/bin/jconsole';'./sumsquares.ijs';'1';'2';'3')
14
```

Comment: Nice answer! IMO it would be worthwhile adding some whitespace to help newer users differentiate the primitives in the sentences.